# Is there any botulism risk in homemade cold brew coffee?

Tags: food-safety, coffee, botulism

Cold brew coffee is known to be less acidic and it stays airtight in fridge overnight. It's not heated before consumption.

There are news on the internet about a well known coffee producer recalling its coffee cans for botulism risk. Is there any botulism risk in homemade cold brew coffee?

Also, does covering the can that contains cold brew in fridge (overnight) airtight increase botulism or any alike food poisoning risk? Should I cover it or keep it open to decrease the risks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a **near zero** probability to get botulism from home brewed cold coffee if done properly (clean containers/vessels, clean fridge, cold fridge temperature...  )

As long as you keep it cold, it should be ok.

(I've not made a thorough google search)

There at least [one report](https://www.foodsafetynews.com/2017/09/death-wish-coffee-pulls-nitro-because-of-botulism-risk/) from 2017 of a [recall](https://www.deathwishcoffee.com/pages/safety-notice-recall-death-wish-nitro) for nitro cold brew; it's pretty much the only report I've seen.

Here's a [report](http://www.bccdc.ca/resource-gallery/Documents/Educational%20Materials/EH/FPS/Food/Nitro_Cold_Brew_Coffee_Food_Safety_Risks.pdf) of the findings, taken from this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Coffee/comments/dl9ltx/nitro_cold_brew_botulism_risks/) thread.

I might have missed it, but it was probably an issue with their processing.

Comment: Max is right.  Coffee beans are not at all risky for botulism contamination, because they're the inner seeds of berries, and they are roasted before you get them.  So really the only way you're going to get botulism spores there is dirt getting mixed in with the beans ... pretty low risk.